# Issue with full HDD

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I "thought " I did everything correctly.
I have 2 HDDs

```
Dev/sda
     sda1
     sda2
Dev/sdg
   sdg1
```

sdg1 "should" have a folder on it called backup3tb in its root

When I look in `/mnt/backup3tb` I see the files I am looking for.

However my sda2 appears to be full.
How do I verify that in fact the backup3tb is on the 3TB `/dev/sdg1` and not an incorrect resource to the main hdd?

Answer (score 0):

From a terminal (stat one with the keys:  ctrl + alt + t ) type

```
df
```

and the first and last columns will tell you if you have mounted sdg1 at /mnt/...  If there is no such entry, then the directory in /mnt is in the root filesystem.

---

To list all the (mounted and unmounted) filesystems, type:

```
sudo blkid
```

The output will also tell you the filesystem type on the partition.

Comment: I have been trying sudo mount /dev/sdg1 /media/backup3tb but I keep getting a warning about   special device /dev/sdg1 does not exist

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options that list mount points together with their backing drive, each with more or less nicely formatted, human-readable output and contextual information:

- Gnome Disks
- GParted
- KDE Partition Manager
- `lsblk` (or `sudo lsblk -f` for more info)
- `df`
- `mount`
- `cat /proc/mounts`

Comment: I prefer `lsblk -f` as it shows more.